# unique_ptr after call to c_str() doesn't point to valid value

Tags: c++

Why after the call c_str() unique_ptr no longer points to valid wstring?

```
wstring encrypt = L"hello";
LPCWSTR decrypted = DecryptString(&EncryptString(encrypt)[0]).get()->c_str();    

unique_ptr<wstring> DecryptString(LPCWSTR str)
{
    unique_ptr<wstring> decryptedStr = make_unique<wstring>();
    decryptedStr.get()->resize(wcslen(str) / sizeof(WCHAR) + 1);

    wstring key = L"123";

    for (int i = 0; i < wcslen(str) / sizeof(WCHAR); i++)
    {
        (*decryptedStr.get())[i] = str[i] ^ key[i % key.size()];
    }

    return decryptedStr;
}
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use `.get()->` on a `std::unique_ptr`.  Just `->` will work as well.

Comment: Why are you using a `std::unique_ptr` here? Why not just `std::wstring`?

Comment: I agree with you unique_ptr is not useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecryptString(&EncryptString(encrypt)[0])` returns a temporary `std::unique_ptr`, which will be destroyed after the statememt immediately. i.e.

```
LPCWSTR decrypted = DecryptString(&EncryptString(encrypt)[0]).get()->c_str();  
// the temporary std::unique_ptr has been destroyed here, 
// the wstring managed by it was destroyed too
// decrypted is dangled now
```

You can use a named `std::unique_ptr` instead:

```
{
    auto p = DecryptString(&EncryptString(encrypt)[0]);
    LPCWSTR decrypted = p.get()->c_str();  
    ...
}
// p and the wstring managed by it is destroyed here
```